# ClusterRoleBinding does not apply

Tags: kubernetes

rbac.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-account
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: my-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["create", "delete", "list"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-cluster-role-binding
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-account
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: my-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

After `kubectl apply -f rbac.yaml` I try:

```
user@host> kubectl auth can-i create pods --as=my-account
no
```

What's wrong with my yaml?

Environment: new minikube.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. The `--as=..` part was wrong:

This works:

```
kubectl auth can-i create pod --as=system:serviceaccount:default:my-account
```